# How to add a image of a Label's part of text background?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, nsattributedstring

Below is the sample code to add a background colour of a attributed string but i want to set a lable attributed string colour to a image. Is there any way to do this?

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range)
```

Comment: You want to add background color to a UIImage?, you can use UIImageView.background color property

Comment: Your description is unclear. Do you want to tint an image?

Comment: @ReinierMelian : Hi i want to add a background image of a specific text of a label

Comment: Your question is still ambigous. What I understood is that you want to use a image as background of your text(this text is in label). right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIColor has a method called "patternImage" where we can set image

```
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text!)
           attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor, value: UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg.png")!) , range: range)
           label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get label's attributed text and apply background color to `UIImageView`

You can fetch attributed text apply to label by `label.attributedText` and from that you can get  `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` and apply to you ImageView

Comment: would you please share some sample code for reference as i am new to swift

Comment: @MaheshPrasadMahalik You should try it by your self, You can print `label.attributedText` where you can see all the attributes apply to label. Next you need to fetch `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` from it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `textColor` property of `UILabel`

```
label.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Pattern.jpg")!)
```